# Unable to close for loop using the algorithmic package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main Ass}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Create
\State Create 
\State Create 
\For{every $T_i$}
\If{$T_i$ is an }
    \If {$T_i$ is of}
    \If {$A \notin$}
    \State add A
    \EndIf
    \EndIf
\ElsIf {$T_i$ is a}
    \If {$T_i$ is}
    \If{A $\in$ DI\_L}
    \If{linked}
    \State Create a 
    \EndIf
    \State add t 
    \EndIf
\ElsIf{$T_i$ is a}
\If{$T_i$ is of $}
\If{A $\in$ }
\State add r
\State add A
\EndIf
\EndIf
\If{$T_i$}
\If{invalid}
\State add w
\ElsIf{$A$}
\State delete A
\EndIf
\EndIf
\If{$c_i$ is found } 
\State delete the
\ElsIf{$a_i$ is found}
\State delete
\EndIf
\EndIf
\Endfor //talking about this for loop not closing, that is line 47
\State Send F
\State Send 
\end{algorithmic} \\that is line 50
\end{algorithm}


\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main Rec}\label{alg:cap2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For {each t} \\that is line 57
\State execute $T_i$

\end{algorithmic} \\that is line 60
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Obviously, I deleted most of the lines of code to make things clearer, even though I closed my for loop, the visual changes aren't reflecting and I am getting multiple errors in compilation the rest appears fine visually

I am getting the following (I commented the code to mark which line each error refers to):

```
Missing number, treated as zero.

‪main.tex, 47‬
<to be read again> 
                   \ALG@b@2@EndFor@0 
l.47 \EndFor
            
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

```
Package algorithmicx Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!.

 
‪main.tex, 50‬
See the algorithmicx package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.50 \end{algorithmic}
                      
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.
```

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.

 
‪main.tex, 57‬
<to be read again> 
                   \ALG@currentblock@0 
l.57 \For
          {each transaction in the linked list}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Extra \endcsname.
\ALG@makebeginrepeat ...\ALG@thisblock \endcsname 
                                                  \relax \def \ALG@thisblock...
l.57 \For
          {each transaction in the linked list}
I'm ignoring this, since I wasn't doing a \csname.
```

```
Package algorithmicx Error: Some blocks are not closed!!!.

 
‪main.tex, 60‬
See the algorithmicx package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.60 \end{algorithmic}
                      
(That was another \errmessage.)
```

Any help would be appreciated, I already tried making sure every opened block is closed and it looks like it, I am suspecting it might me some confusing with using the packages but I can't seem to figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count the number of `\If` commands and of the corresponding `\EndIf`. You'll see that they don't match.

If you properly indent the nested structures, you'll see.

I don't know where to precisely add the missing `\EndIf`. Here's a possibility, fix it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Main Ass}\label{alg:cap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State Create
\State Create 
\State Create 
\For{every $T_i$}
  \If{$T_i$ is an }
    \If {$T_i$ is of}
      \If {$A \notin$}
        \State add A
      \EndIf
    \EndIf
  \ElsIf {$T_i$ is a}
    \If {$T_i$ is}
      \If{A $\in$ DI\_L}
        \If{linked}
          \State Create a 
        \EndIf
          \State add t 
      \EndIf
    \ElsIf{$T_i$ is a}
      \If{$T_i$ is of}
        \If{A $\in$ }
          \State add r
          \State add A
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
      \If{$T_i$}
        \If{invalid}
          \State add w
        \ElsIf{$A$}
          \State delete A
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
    \EndIf % <--- Here?
    \If{$c_i$ is found } 
      \State delete the
    \ElsIf{$a_i$ is found}
      \State delete
    \EndIf
  \EndIf
\EndFor
\State Send F
\State Send 
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: while counting the if statements do we include or exclude the elsif

Comment: @Sergio No, we don't. An `\If` can have as many `\ElsIf` as you want.